# Как упростить и переписать код слайдера с JQuery на ванильный JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть файлики с простой логикой события: нажал на кнопку - появляется один элемент, исчезает другой. И эти файлики разрослись до неприятно больших размеров, из-за чего появляются неприятные моменты при загрузке страницы.

Это пример моего кода. У меня шесть слайдов, по клику на них происходят следующие события.

```
$('.slide-1').focus(function () {
    $('.number-1').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    $('.number-1').css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
    $('.number-1').css('margin-left', '3.5vw');
    $('.number-2').css('font-weight', 400);
    $('.number-2').css('color', 'rgb(203, 203, 203)');
    $('.number-2').css('margin-left', 0);
    $('.number-3').css('font-weight', 400);
    $('.number-3').css('color', 'rgb(203, 203, 203)');
    $('.number-3').css('margin-left', 0);
    $('.number-4').css('font-weight', 400);
    $('.number-4').css('color', 'rgb(203, 203, 203)');
    $('.number-4').css('margin-left', 0);
    $('.number-5').css('font-weight', 400);
    $('.number-5').css('color', 'rgb(203, 203, 203)');
    $('.number-5').css('margin-left', 0);
    $('.number-6').css('font-weight', 400);
    $('.number-6').css('color', 'rgb(203, 203, 203)');
    $('.number-6').css('margin-left', 0);
});
$('.slide-1').click(function () {
    $('.down-1').css('display', 'flex');
    $('.down-2').css('display', 'none');
    $('.down-3').css('display', 'none');
    $('.down-4').css('display', 'none');
    $('.down-5').css('display', 'none');
    $('.down-6').css('display', 'none');
    $('.arrow-1').css('display', 'none');
    $('.arrow-2').css('display', 'block');
    $('.arrow-3').css('display', 'block');
    $('.arrow-4').css('display', 'block');
    $('.arrow-5').css('display', 'block');
    $('.arrow-6').css('display', 'block');
    $('.main-text-1').css('display', 'flex');
});
```

Мне необходимо переписать логику слайдера на чистом JS. Хотя бы просто потому, что хочу уметь это делать. Поддержка браузеров ниже IE11 не требуется. Насколько сильно это зависит от кода на JS?

Comment: А почему бы не взять jquery девелоперской версии и не посмотреть как там на чистом JS реализовано? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.slide').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).css('flex-grow', 15).siblings().css('flex-grow', 1);
});
```

Оставлено на JQuery. Переписано

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.down-1').css('display', 'flex');
```

Аналогично

```
document.querySelector('.down-1').style.display = "flex"
```

так же и обработчики событий:

```
$('.slide-1').click(function () {
...
})
```

Аналогично

```
document.querySelector('.slide-1').onclick = function(){
...
}
```

Comment: `$('.slide-1').click  равносильно document.querySelector('.slide-1').onclick` - нет, не равносильно. Может быть автор на каждый слайдер лепит отдельный класс, но в целом указанные аналогии не являются равнозначными

Comment: окей, не то слово - аналогично

Comment: Спасибо, а как быть с событиями mouseenter, mouseover и focus? @nueq

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, у меня на каждый слайд отдельный класс. Этот пример верен?

Comment: @Stanislav в данном конкретном случае с учетом того, что 1 класс - 1 слайдер  -- да. Но коду в принципе нужен рефакторинг, ибо так никто не делает